# Autofac in Asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, autofac

I want/need to compile autofac with asp.net mvc 2 website. I want to step thru the source to see how it works. But here is my problem. The binaries for mvc dll is apparently bound for asp.net mvc  1. I am having trouble working out what the settings for the project file need to be for .Net 3.5 and asp.net mvc 2. one is the NET35 directive but I still get errors that   out  is not a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're running vs2008. Autofac relies on vs2010 even when targeting .net 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting assembly binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: well I am on asp.net mvc 2 so I think that I should have the v2 version my only dependency not mix and match but thanks